# Jenkinsfile to run Terraform

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, terraform, jenkins-groovy

following this tutorial 
https://medium.com/@devopslearning/100-days-of-devops-day-34-terraform-pipeline-using-jenkins-a3d81975730f

I want to be run a terraform file from Jenkins
I have installed Terraform plugin version 1.0.9
I go create a new pipeline project
on the pipeline tab I choose pipeline script and paste the below script

```
node {
env.PATH += ":/opt/terraform_0.7.13/"


 stage ('Terraform Plan') {
 sh 'terraform plan -no-color -out=create.tfplan'
}

// Optional wait for approval
input 'Deploy stack?'

stage ('Terraform Apply') {
sh "terraform --version"
}
```

This is the console output

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Terraform Plan)
[Pipeline] sh
[aws_terraform] Running shell script
+ terraform plan -no-color -out=create.tfplan
/var/lib/jenkins-slave/workspace/ow/ow_eng/aws_terraform@tmp/durable-53622951/script.sh: line 2: terraform: command not found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Do you have Terraform downloaded and on your path on the machine that executes that?

Comment: I have the plugin , do i need Terraform installed on my jenkins machine if so does it have to be on master or slave , what is the best practice ? should terraform be on a separate vm /container and loaded each time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `terraform` binary is not installed on the jenkins slave that is executing the pipeline. The binary must be installed to have the plugin work

Comment: We have one master at least 5 slaves , does it need to be installed on each ? or installed on one and then I target just that slave ?

Comment: @user17970 installed on one and targeting that slave should be just fine!

Comment: @StephenG: where did u installed Terraform on Jenkins?Could you please guide.

Comment: @AWS_Developer anywhere in the $PATH

Comment: @StephenG is it necesary to install Terraform plugin. I have kept terraform.exe in my bitbucket itlsef where Jenkinsfile is present but still I am getting terraform: command not found error.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use a docker image for running this you can use this snippet:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'hashicorp/terraform:light'
      args '--entrypoint='
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Terraform Plan') { 
      steps {
        sh 'terraform plan -no-color -out=create.tfplan' 
      }
    }
    // Optional wait for approval
    input 'Deploy stack?'

    stage ('Terraform Apply') {
      sh "terraform --version"
    }
  }
}
```

Be aware that you will need to install the [docker pipeline plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin). The trick is here to redefine the entrypoint because the official terraform image already defines an entrypoint to the `terraform` executable.

Comment: Your answer looks great but when I try it I get `sh: /bin/bash: not found`. I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: And `sh '#!/bin/sh%nterraform --version'` works... (replace %n...)